# XPath Selector + keep the html structure

Tags: xml

I get a distant xml file with this structure:

```
<text>
    <table>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                  <td>String1</td>
                  <td>String2</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</text>
```

I want to get the datas and keep the structure of the table.
But if I define in the XPath selector this: text, I get all the datas without the structure

```
e.g. String1String2...
```

From this xml, is it possible to get the datas and keep the html structure of the table?

```
e.g. <table><tbody><tr><td>String1</td><td>String2</td>...
```

If no, can you explain me how I must proceed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you just want to remove the whitespace; why do you need XPath for that?

Comment: Hello, i use Drupal and create a view with the remote xml file. In view, for each row i must define several fields with XPath selector (id, text, description, date...) to build a list of datas.

Comment: Don't know about Drupal, but you may want to try : `.//td/text()`, that xpath normally return individual text within each `<td>` separately

Comment: Hello, i don't want get only the text but all the elements under a XPath (<....> and texts). If I have in my xml this structure : <table><tr>..., I want get these elements and the texts inside of these elements. Is it possible to get this with a defined Xpath ? (e.g. .//table/html or .//table/string ???). Thanks.